# Speech Synthesis API not working in Firefox on Manjaro

Tags: firefox, speech-synthesis, manjaro

I installed speech-dispatcher which works on the command line but not in firefox.

The voices array in firefox is empty.

I installed speech-dispatcher and festival

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
msg.text = "Good Morning"

window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

speechSynthesis.getVoices() // empty array
```

If I type: espeak "hello" it works in command line but not firefox.

Comment: Bug Ticket at Mozilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1753637